# How to disable grunt uglify task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

The **uglify** task takes too long to complete, it is difficult while development, How can I disable the task without removing from `grunt.registerTask`, because other tasks are also calling uglify

```
uglify: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      banner: '<%= meta.text%>'
    },
    files: {
      '<%= assets %>': '<%= concat.assets%>'
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved the issue

```
uglify: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      banner: '<%= meta.text%>'
    },
    files: {
     // commented this line to stop uglify task
     // '<%= assets %>': '<%= concat.assets%>'
    }
  }
},
```